# Stochastic Independence of $\tan(U_1)$ and $\tan(U_1+U_2)$ for uniform independent $U_1,U_2$

Tags: probability, convolution, independence, uniform-distribution

I found the following statement in Stoyanov's book on counterexamples (Section 7.2) quite interesting: Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $(0,\pi)$. Then $\tan(U_1)$ and $\tan(U_1+U_2)$ are independent.

This is taken from https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177698885 and I am really confused by that: To my mind, they say in the last two sections that $U_1+U_2$ is also uniformly distributed and independent of $U_1$ (which would imply the statement) - this is clearly not true so that I must have misunderstood.

I would appreciate a clarification of this and I would like to know in what sense and why there actually is independence between $\tan(U_1)$ and $\tan(U_1+U_2)$.

Comment: This is interesting! $\tan $ is not one-to -one on $(0,2\pi)$ so you cannot say that independence of $\tan (U_1)$ and $\tan (U_1+U_2)$ implies that of $U_1$ and $U_1+U_2$.  Note that $\tan (U_1)$ is not even defined when $U_1=\pi /2$ but this event has probability $0$. The weird behavior an $\tan $ may lead to this result and I don't have a proof right now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you think this might be extended to other functions which are periodic in $(0, 2\pi)$ and odd with respect to $\pi$? Very interesting indeed.

Comment: The statements there should be saying that $P$ has an arbitrary distribution, and $Q \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \pi)$, independent of $P$. Then $[(P + Q) \mod \pi] \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \pi)$ and it is independent from $P$. The mod part convention is stated in the last sentence in P. 2 (P. 917).

Comment: @BGM That's much better, thanks. The proof is okay if $P$ is also uniform, I'll also try to understand the general case.